# KDB Window Join Limit Error

Tags: kdb

I'm trying to do a window join on the data set below (just playing around with it).

```
w:(((1%24)%2);0f){"z"$y-x}\:dd.time;
f:`sym`time;
wj[w;f;dd;(dd;(::;`price))];
```

and this results in a error:

```
k){[e;d;a;b]e@'d@\:a+!b-a}
'limit
!:
205558234298187785
```

dd table:

```
sym     time                    price
B1VVGZ5 2015-07-30T12:47:57.000 240.9
0216238 2015-07-30T08:16:22.383 5.19
0216238 2015-07-30T08:18:36.000 5.195
0216238 2015-07-30T08:18:36.217 5.195
0216238 2015-07-30T08:22:13.527 5.2
0216238 2015-07-30T08:22:13.730 5.2
0216238 2015-07-30T08:26:34.437 5.2025
0216238 2015-07-30T08:29:00.920 5.2
0216238 2015-07-30T08:29:01.113 5.2
0216238 2015-07-30T08:29:01.113 5.2
```

and meta on that table:

```
c     t   f   a
sym   s     
time  z     
price f
```

The other oddity is that this code worked and then didn't work.  Any ideas on what's going on?

EDIT:  Exactly how I reproduce this error:

```
dd:select [10] sym:symbol,time:"z"$FILL_DATE,price:FILL_PRICE from update symbol:`$Sedol from select from fillData where date=2015.07.30;

w:(((1%24)%2);0f){"z"$y-x}\:dd.time
f:`sym`time

wj[w;f;dd;(dd;(max;`price))]
```

Answer (score 1):

[Take a look at the list of kdb+ errors](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/error-list/)

> limit ->  tried to generate a list longer than 2,000,000,000, or serialized object is > 2GB, or 'type if trying to serialize a nested object which has > 2 billion elements.

This could explain why the code worked previously (smaller dataset?).

Which version of q are you using? I would recommend upgrading to 3+ [as the vector size limit was removed in version 3.0](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/releases/ChangesIn3.0/).

Comment: it's the same table...and that table is only 10 rows.  I'm not sure why it's trying to generate a list of more than 2mm rows.

Comment: Hmm... Can you double check your code? I copied your exact table as above and the code runs fine for me. Tested on version 2.8 and 3.1.

Comment: It works fine when I upgrade to version 3.3.  Perhaps a bug in earlier versions?

Comment: I seem to still get this error in v3.1, but not in v3.3

Comment: Strange... It works for me in all versions i tested. Would you mind posting the exact commands you run? Including where you create the table?

Comment: Added my exact commands above.  Maybe something I'm doing in how I create dd?

Comment: The select [10] is not actually selecting 10. You can verify by putting - `show count dd` after the first statement. Try changing it to `10#select from ...`.

Comment: I believe the issue here is the field name sym is causing that syntax to get messed up, and is selecting the sym file instead of the sym column. Strange error!

Comment: Hm, I tried changing sym to symb, but I still get the error.  Not quite sure what to make of it.

Comment: I think I found the issue {"z"$y-x} .. if i take out the "z"$ conversion it works...don't quite understand why.

Comment: Taking out the "z"$ shouldn't make a difference to the above code... Nothing else changed in your select statement? Were you getting counts>10 before?

Comment: Nope.. when i do    w:(((1%24)%2);0f){y-x}\:dd.time   then   w2:(((1%24)%2);0f){"z"$y-x}\:dd.time    then   
w~w2     i get false

Comment: In that case dd is not as you have posted above - I ran the exact code above and w~w2 returned true.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  Still a bit confused, but that's alright...maybe taking my eyes off this will help.

Comment: Sure - not sure how much I helped... Hope you figure it out!

Comment: 32bit version or 64bit version? Also, we can't reproduce your table exactly without the "fillData" table it relies on. Can you post an actual dataset that we can reproduce?